# Word for eyes "pleading for approval"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases, expressions, phrase-requests

I would like to know a word/phrase that can be used to describe the eyes of a person seeking/pleading approval. Similar to the colloquial usage 'puppy eyes'.

Sample usage:

> Her mother insisted on going home after school. She looked at her with **puppy eyes** pleading her mother to take her to the park.

Comment: Can you please add a sample sentence were the word could be used?

Comment: Sample usage: Her mother insisted on going home after school. She looked at her with _puppy eyes_ pleading her mother to take her to the park.

Comment: Why the close vote?

Comment: As a note, the term is actually "puppy dog eyes." https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/puppy_dog_eyes

Comment: I'll note that "mournful eyes" is a common expression, though it doesn't quite capture the meaning of "pleading".

Answer (score 1):

**pleading** [OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/145543?rskey=92Hh7t&result=3&isAdvanced=false#eid) adj

> that pleads; esp. entreating, beseeching, imploring.

As in:

> - 1901   ‘H. McHugh’ John Henry   I hate to have a girl plant her    **pleading** peepers on me.
> - 1968   A. K. Armah Beautyful Ones are not yet Born    The boatman's eyes were no longer the diffuse, vaguely **pleading eyes**
>     of the hireling the man had seen the first time.

Pleading eyes is synonymous with that begging look, forlorn puppy look.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/imploring

imploring
(ɪmplɔrɪŋ  )
ADJECTIVE [ADJ n]

An imploring look, cry, or letter shows that you want someone to do something very much and are afraid they may not do it.

Frank looked at Jim with imploring eyes.

imploringly ADVERB [ADV after v]
Michael looked at him imploringly, eyes brimming with tears.

Answer (score -4):

**Downcast**

> adjective
>
> 1.(of a person's eyes) looking downwards. "Her modestly downcast eyes"

**Piteous**

> adjective
>
> 1.deserving or arousing pity. "John looked at Maria, his face piteous"

**Forlorn**

> adjective
>
> 1.pitifully sad and abandoned or lonely. "Forlorn figures at bus stops"
>
> 2.(of an aim or endeavour) unlikely to succeed or be fulfilled. "A forlorn attempt to escape"

These are just my favourites, and out of them I most recommend forlorn. It's a  *dignified* word, if you know what I mean. It lends a certain *je ne sais quoi* to the whole shebang. Otherwise, downcast would be my choice.

Oh yeah, my "source" for these words is Google, albeit with a few changes.

Comment: Thanks. However, I would like to have a word where a person succeeds in his attempt at pleading. Like the sample, "Her mother insisted on going home after school. She looked at her with _puppy eyes_ pleading her mother to take her to the park"

Comment: There isn't a single word for that, as far as I know. It's a separate statement of its own. If you want to show her succeeding, you'd have to write something like 'It worked like a charm; as always, her mother melted. "For forty-five minutes *only*, okay? I mean it this time."'

Comment: I am sorry for not being clear. I am actually looking for an alternate for "puppy eyes"